# How to compare large number in PHP?

Tags: php, bignum

I confuse that how I aseert quite large number by PHPUnit.
I wrote fibonacci number. But in case 100, I wrote below.

```
http://github.com/sanemat/kata-fibonacci-phpunit/commit/b6b2945d2eff1b95e7e25b8be8c7bff11098d44d
```

I expect this return TRUE.
It failed.

```
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
```

I understood 'never compare for equality.' and so how to aseert it?
At the end, I compare with to_string each other.
How to compare large number in PHP ?

```
http://github.com/sanemat/kata-fibonacci-phpunit/commit/70a0e47bc0737be47da8fe8726634edd851d940d
```

I feel it as bad smell. But I do not know better way.
Please tell me how do you assert it?

```
====
php > $a = 354224848179261915075;
php > echo $a;
3.5422484817926E+20
php > $b = 3.5422484817926E+20;
php > echo $b;
3.5422484817926E+20
php > echo ($a == $b) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
FALSE
php > echo gmp_cmp($a, $b);
PHP Warning:  gmp_cmp(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type in php shell code on line 1
php > echo (strval($a) == strval($b)) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
TRUE
====

environment
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.33.6-147.2.4.fc13.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 23 17:14:44 UTC 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ php --version
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 22 2010 15:57:00) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: The problem here is that to accurately display Fibonacci 100 you need a long long int (96 bits). Technically for integers over 32 bits in PHP you have to use an array of integers, making sure to carry bits from one element to another and account for orders of magnitude. If you don't want to handle that, just use the BCMath library.

Comment: I solved my problem by using BCMath library. Thank you for your helping. I want to know more. Your explanation sounds good, but I do not understand it. What word can I google it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with large numbers, there is [BCMath libray](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) of PHP.

Comment: Thanks! I solved this. http://github.com/sanemat/kata-fibonacci-phpunit/commit/2f0bdc3a309caae21ab4fb7f98295b8d4d0c5046